# Action.BeginInvoke and Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, multithreading, begininvoke

I understand that System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal flows with most asynchronous invocations in .Net 4.0+.  However, it looks like it is reset before the AsyncResult callback is called.  I know what I need to change in this particular case to fix it, but I'm wondering why the framework does this here (and not after the invocation of the AsyncResult callback).

As a secondary question - will the AsyncResult callback always run on the same thread that the "work" was executed on, or is this not guaranteed?

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPricipal = CustomPrincipal;
//ManagedThreadID is 101 (for example)
Promise.When(() => {
    //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal still Custom Principal
    //As expected

    //ManagedThreadID is 254 (for example - a different thread, as expected)
}); 

public static IPromise<T> When<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal still CustomPrincipal
    //As expected
    Promise<T> p = new Promise<T>();
    action.BeginInvoke((result) =>
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal NOT CustomPrincipal (it's now a GenericPrincipal object) - reset by framework?
        //ManagedThreadId is still 254 (as expected)
        try
        {
            p.Complete(action.EndInvoke(result));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            p.Complete(ex);
        }
    }, null);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that cannot work.  Using a delegate's BeginInvoke method is never not a problem.  Just don't use it, anything else is better.  Like Task.

Comment: @HansPassant - in the spirit of trying to gain a deeper understanding, if it shouldn't be used, why is it in the framework at all?

Comment: They could not resist adding it.  Not framework, it is a CLR feature.  Which is why it doesn't work.